# Reading data from an HID device from userspace in OSX

Tags: objective-c, c, macos

I need to be able to read some data from an HID device that is not a keyboard, mouse, etc...

I have scoured through the apple docs but they are rather complex, and the code example span both C and C++. I'm assuming since this is user space it can be done with objective-c, if not though then C would be my preference since that's what I have been using thus far while working on this. I have been able to read the USB ports find my device with the matching dictionary and create and iterator for it, I'm not sure of the next step in the work flow to start reading the data though. Can anyone provide me some guidance with this, or a good work flow outline I should follow?

My Current process is:
- Create HID manager
- Create a matching dictionary 
- Specify device in the matching dictionary 
- Register the matching dictionary to the HID manager 
- Register a callback from the device removal to the HID manager
- (Where I'm stuck) Getting data from the device

Thanks!

Comment: @DarkDust Unfortunately that issue focuses on a C++ solution was hoping for something in C/Objective-C.

Comment: Actually, the whole IOKit stuff is pure C. The accepted answer merely put the whole stuff into C++ methods, he could have just used C functions as well. Apart from throwing an exception, I haven't spotted any C++-specific stuff inside those methods.